# Variable Argument List following 'const std::string&' messes up the stack

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

I have a function: `std::string format(const std::string sformat, ...);`
It basically works like a fancy sprintf().

Since I call that function a lot I wanted to pass the format string as a ref: `const std::string& sformat`.
Unfortunately va_start() seems to have problems finding the right spot on the stack to the variable argument list.

If I remove the '&' it works fine.

Two questions: **A:** Do I even need the reference in order to prevent a copy of `sformat` during the call, or is the optimizer clever enough to just do a pass-by-ref in the background?
**B:** What can I do to prevent a pass-by-value of the format string and still don't confuse va_start() ?

My guess is: pass-by-pointer. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: "Or is there a better solution" How about dropping variadic packs and start using variadic templates?

Comment: This is all very compiler-specific, so can you please tell us what compiler you're using? What version of it? And what system you're targeting?

Comment: Use a [variadic template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start : If `parm_n` is declared with reference type or with a type not compatible with the type that results from default argument promotions, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: I'm using (have to use) VS2010, I'm not sure where to find the exact version number of the compiler. The info says: VS10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. Target systems are: WinXP and Win7(32/64). Project is a DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of variadic templates. Haven't used those before. Looks like a nice solution but my compiler doesn't like it - see my other comment. (yes, I HAVE to use that compiler)

Comment: Have you tried boost format?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use third party libraries on that project. And (for some reason) boost is considered a third party lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace details {
  std::string format(char const* sformat, ...) {
    // code
  }
}
template<class...Args>
std::string format(std::string const& str, Args const&... args) {
  return details::format( str.data(), args... );
}
```

As a bonus, I can write a `to_pod` helper:

```
namespace details {
  std::string format(char const* sformat, ...) {
    // code
  }
}
template<class T>
T const& to_pod(T const& t){ return t; }
template<class Char, class Attribs>
Char const* to_pod( std::basic_string<Char, Attribs> const& str ) {
  return t.data();
}
template<class...Args>
std::string format(std::string const& str, Args const&... args) {
  return details::format( str.data(), to_pod(args)... );
}
```

and now I can pass `std::string`s as things past the first argument, and they are auto-converted to `char const*` pointers to their buffer.

...

If you do not have a C++11 compiler (say MSVC 2010), your best bet is probably to just write overloads.

```
std::string format(std::string const& str) {
  return details::format( str.data() );
}
template<class A0>
std::string format(std::string const& str, A0 const& a0) {
  return details::format( str.data(), to_pod(a0) );
}
template<class A0, class A1>
std::string format(std::string const& str, A0 const& a0, A1 const& a1) {
  return details::format( str.data(), to_pod(a0), to_pod(a1) );
}
// etc
```

You are probably not going to want more than 10 arguments.

Comment: I'll mark this as solution because it's a good solution for current compilers.

Comment: Addition to my last comment: Unfortunately, the compiler I have to use, doesn't know variadic templates. So, I guess I'll go with multiple overloads and/or pass-by-pointer.